# MVC3 Unicode display on View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, unicode

I have an MVC3 razor page that does not appear to be rendering the Spanish Characters it needs to.  It replaces the characters with a ??.  So me gustaría would be be gustar??a

The strings are also rendered with the @html.raw() helper, but removing this does not fix the issue either.

Originally, in my layout I had

```
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

But when I changed it to utf-16 it did not fix the problem.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about putting correct charset string to your file, but about actual encoding of this file. You must ensure that your file is UTF-8 encoded.

I can recommend to:

- Download free tool called [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- Open your file with Notepad++
- Go to menu "Encoding", submenu "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM"
- Look at your Spanish letters, they may need to be replaced.
- Save the file.

Then recompile your website and try again. Hope this helps.

Comment: This has actually helped me to look in the right direction!  I was uploading the document and parsing that file as ASCII and not UTF-8.  Thanks!